# How to fetch data in arrayList from jsp

Tags: struts2

This is my form in jsp

```
<form action="submit">
  <tr class="row" id="item1">
  <td><input type="text" name="type" class="type"  style="width: 50px"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="color" class="color" style="width: 50px"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="qty" style="width: 50px"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="unitprice"   class="unitPrice" style="width: 50px"/></td>
 </tr>

...
 <tr class="row" id="itemN">
  <td><input type="text" name="type" class="type"  style="width: 50px"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="color" class="color" style="width: 50px"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="qty" style="width: 50px"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="unitprice"   class="unitPrice" style="width: 50px"/></td>
 </tr>

</form>
```

I want to fetch data which may contain 1 to N items and each item contais `type` `color` `qty` and `unitprice`. I want to store all these data in ArrayList variable.
How to do this?

Comment: Typically XWork  type conversion is doing that.

Comment: XWork is showing 
error for import 
`import com.atlassian.confluence.core.ConfluenceActionSupport`;

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [Tabular Input](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/tabular-inputs.html)

Comment: Not understainding it any other example

Comment: What you didnt understand. You basically have to iterate over your bean. Like e.g if you have a bean(lets name it Product) and the attributes are type color qty and unitprice. So instead of setting the individual properties, you make a list of your Product bean and then iterate over that list and set the values in the JSP using dot notation. e.g `<s:textfield name="Product.color[%{#Product.index}]" value="%{Product.color}" />`

Comment: i have to only fetch the values from jsp tp arraylist